# Point Gray Research Triclops only reads 1 frame

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, camera-calibration, stereoscopy

I'm using a Point Gray Research BumbleBee 2 camera and their SDK. I have this loop to grab frames consecutively, but it's not working. It grabs the first frame ok but triclopsGetImage() doesn't appear to update the contents of refImage(R|L) as the images shown are just from the first frame... Anyone have any experience with Point Gray Cameras or the triclops SDK?

```
   //There's more code above

   int nframes = 20;
   for (int frame = 0; frame < nframes ; frame++ ) {

       te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR );
       te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL );

       cv::Mat leftIm(cv::Mat::zeros(refImageR.nrows,refImageR.ncols,CV_8UC1));
       cv::Mat rightIm(cv::Mat::zeros(refImageR.nrows,refImageR.ncols,CV_8UC1));
       int counter = 0;
       for (int row=0;row<refImageR.nrows;row++) {
           for (int col=0;col<refImageR.ncols;col++) {
               leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL.data[counter];
               rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR.data[counter];
               counter++;
           }
       }

       imshow("LeftIm",leftIm);
       imshow("RightIm",rightIm);

       cv::waitKey(1000);
       cout << "frame = " << frame << endl;
   }
```

**EDIT**

Ok, this isn't elegant in any way but I think it helps. Even doing this I'm only getting the contents of the first frame.
I'm thinking that either the cv::Mat leftIm and rightIm are keeping the data and not being updated or there's something wrong with the triclops.

```
TriclopsContext triclops;
```

From the header file it says
"TriclopsContext is a pointer to an internal structure that maintains all the image and bookkeeping information necessary to the Triclops library. It is the container for all parameters"

```
for (int frame = 1; frame < nframes ; frame++ ) {

       if (frame == 1) {
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR1 );
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL1 );
       } else if (frame == 2) {
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR2 );
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL2 );
       } else if (frame == 3) {
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR3 );
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL3 );
       } else if (frame == 4) {
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR4 );
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL4 );
       } else if (frame == 5) {
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_RIGHT, &refImageR5 );
            te = triclopsGetImage( triclops, TriImg_RECTIFIED, TriCam_LEFT, &refImageL5 );
       }

       cv::Mat leftIm(cv::Mat::zeros(refImageR1.nrows,refImageR1.ncols,CV_8UC1));
       cv::Mat rightIm(cv::Mat::zeros(refImageR1.nrows,refImageR1.ncols,CV_8UC1));
       int counter = 0;
       for (int row=0;row<refImageR1.nrows;row++) {
           for (int col=0;col<refImageR1.ncols;col++) {
               //leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL.data[counter];
               //rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR.data[counter];
               if (frame == 1) {
                    leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL1.data[counter];
                    rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR1.data[counter];
               } else if (frame == 2) {
                    leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL2.data[counter];
                    rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR2.data[counter];
               } else if (frame == 3) {
                    leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL3.data[counter];
                    rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR3.data[counter];
               } else if (frame == 4) {
                    leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL4.data[counter];
                    rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR4.data[counter];
               } else if (frame == 5) {
                    leftIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageL5.data[counter];
                    rightIm.at<uchar>(row,col) = refImageR5.data[counter];
               }

               counter++;
           }
       }

       imshow("LeftIm",leftIm);
       imshow("RightIm",rightIm);

       cv::waitKey(1000);
       cout << "frame = " << frame << endl;
   }
```

Comment: What is `triclopsGetImage` returning?

Comment: te returned from triclopsGetImage is reporting a 0, indicating it worked ok. Flags a non zero value for an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example in the Triclops SDK folder it shows their program calling the following methods before getting the image:

```
error = triclopsPreprocess( context, &inputData );
error = triclopsStereo( context );
```

You might need to call these at the end of your loop to tell the camera to calculate disparities for the next frame.